# Como selecionar vários checkBoxs?

Tags: java, javafx

Eu tenho um loop `for`, no qual eu crio um novo `checkBox` todas vez que ele passa pela rotina/loop. Eu estou adicionando esses "checks" dentro de um item de um `treeTableView`. Queria saber, como eu poderia marcar todos os checks criados.

Como eu posso recuperar "o valor (o checkBox)" para poder selecionar ?

a criação do check está da seguinte forma:

```
 for (int y = 0; y < lista.size(); y++) {
        CheckBoxW checkBoxW = new CheckBoxW();
        item = new TreeItem<?>(gp, new HBox(checkBoxW, label));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A classe *CheckBox* tem o método `setSelected(Boolean)`, com ele vc vai conseguir mudar o status.
para recuperar o valor do `checkBox` deve usar o seguinte

```
      getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(i).getChildren()...
```

Desse jeito vai conseguir percorrer cada `item` do *TreeTableView*.